# Minikube: automatically pull all the latest images from GCR and restarted those pods

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Is there a way to configure the minikube cluster to automatically pull "all" the latest docker images from GCR for all the pods in the cluster and restarted those pods once you start your minikube cluster?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [AlwaysPullImages admission controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#alwayspullimages) which forces the `imagePullPolicy` to `Always` which will repull images on pod restart. And then just restart all your pods.